# Default JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I am using Pharo smalltalk image with latest seaside loaded.

I had loaded the JQBaseTheme in my project.

What  should i do  to bypass  the colourful,large view of the UITab and show a simple UITab as shown in 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the default style of JQueryUI you can provide your own styles that set font-family and font-size as you like. On the page you mention they use http://jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css with the following CSS rule:

```
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the method JQBaseTheme>>updateRoot: you will see that it adds the stylesheet url for that theme.

```
anHtmlRoot styleSheet url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com...'
```

You could implelement updateRoot: in your Seaside component to add the stylesheet url of the page you referenced or any other available css resource you would like to use.